# Whether the random numbers generated by $urandom_range() are 'cyclical random'?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

It's a Sample from SystemVerilog for Verification-A Guide to Learning the Testbench Language Features.
In class Driver, if `drop==0` , transaction will be lost. Why `drop = ($urandom_range(0,99) == 0)` can randomly drop 1 out of every 100 transactions in its notes? I think it's a random drop with a 1% probability.

```
//Test using a callback for error injection
    class Driver_cbs_drop extends Driver_cbs;
      
      virtual task pre_tx(ref Transaction tr, ref bit drop);
           // Randomly drop 1 out of every 100 transactions
           drop = ($urandom_range(0,99) == 0);
      endtask

    endclass

    program automatic test;
     Environment env;

     initial begin
       env = new();
       env.gen_cfg();
       env.build();

       begin // Create error injection callback
         Driver_cbs_drop dcd = new();
         env.drv.cbs.push_back(dcd); // Put into driverÕs Q
       end

       env.run();
       env.wrap_up();
     end
    endprogram
```

```
//Driver class with callbacks
    class Driver;
     Driver_cbs cbs[$];
     task run();
       bit drop;
       Transaction tr;

       forever begin
         drop = 0;
         agt2drv.get(tr);
         foreach (cbs[i]) cbs[i].pre_tx(tr, drop);
           if (!drop) continue;

           transmit(tr);

         foreach (cbs[i]) cbs[i].post_tx(tr);
       end
     endtask
    endclass
```

```
// Base callback class
    virtual class Driver_cbs; // Driver callbacks 
      virtual task pre_tx(ref Transaction tr, ref bit drop);
      // By default, callback does nothing
      endtask

      virtual task post_tx(ref Transaction tr);
      // By default, callback does nothing
      endtask
    endclass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$urandom_range is a probabilistic distribution function; it is not cyclical. Either the comment is not precisely worded, or the code was not implemented properly.